# If I buy a rigged object, will the bones import if they weren't made in blender?

Tags: bones

Whether the rigged object I buy is 3ds or obj or even another format, how could the bones import as blender bones if they were made in another program?

Answer (score 2):

You can't import **.3ds** files into Blender.

**.obj** files don't include bones or joints.

It is close to impossible to import complex rigs from different 3D applications.

**.fbx** files can contain bones/joints and animation.